# How to configure Service Fabric and Microsoft Operations Managment Suite for Reliable Actor perf counters?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have Service Fabric ETW events set up in OMS and I found [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-diagnostics) documentation on actor performance counters.

What I don't know is how do I get these performance counters into OMS?

Can anyone point me to some documentation or examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the monitoring agent is installed on the nodes of the scale set:

   - Go to the Settings page of OMS
   - Select to 'Connected Sources', 'Windows Servers' to find the bits, workspaceID and keys.
   - **Or** use VMSS extension like shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-vmss-oms/azuredeploy.json). (search for 'MicrosoftMonitoringAgent').
2. Once the monitoring agent is running, on the OMS portal in 'Settings', select 'Data', 'Windows Performance Counters'

   - Configure the performance counters you want to track and a sample interval.
   - Like "Service Fabric Actor(*)\Average milliseconds per lock wait" - 10s

(Data should show up in 'Log Search' under 'Perf')